# import another program as module

Tags: python

i searched my problem on stack and i didt find the solution so i come here to asking u about that .im learnin python with the book 'OReilly.Introducing.Python' and in chapter 5 in module section .the author says u can save a program and use in in another program as module when the 2 programs are saved in 1 directory. this is the fist program using as module.
report.py

```
def get_description(): # see the docstring below?
"""Return random weather, just like the pros"""
    from random import choice
    possibilities = ['rain', 'snow', 'sleet', 'fog', 'sun', 'who knows']
    return choice(possibilities)
```

and the main program is this :

```
import report
description = report.get_description()
print("Today's weather:", description)
```

its a simple program i know when i want to import that it apears with this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\python\Lib\weather.py", line 1, in 
    import report
  File "H:\python\Lib\report.py", line 2
    """Return random weather, just like the pros"""
                                                  ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

i tried to change directory and copy that to lib folder or scripts and this is my sys.path:
H:\python\Lib
C:\Windows\System32
H:\python\Lib\idlelib
H:\python\python35.zip
H:\python\DLLs
H:\python\lib
H:\python
H:\python\lib\site-packages

Comment: I  think you have to indent your docstring in the first prog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the error says, you must ident the docstring:

```
def get_description(): # see the docstring below?
    """Return random weather, just like the pros"""
    from random import choice
    possibilities = ['rain', 'snow', 'sleet', 'fog', 'sun', 'who knows']
    return choice(possibilities)
```

Comment: it worded but how :| . it was the book exactly same program .and didnt work now with this code its working.i thought my problem is the program is not importing :| .tnx sir